# Visual Studio Solution breaks when touching AppView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that compiles, but when I touch anything in the visual editor and compile again it creates a new auto generated class that breaks the solution and stops compiling:

[Before touching any visual:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpHMz.png)

[After touching it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFLLT.png)

So I can't understand what's wrong, even if I don't modify a single line, it just crashes.

```
: Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0260  Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'AppView'; another partial declaration of this type exists

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0111  Type 'AppView' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types
```

[Auto Generated crushing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txu8x.png)

Any suggestions?